# Creating new Pages in TYPO3 V11 results in strange slugs "default-..."

Tags: typo3, slug

Creating new Pages results in strange slugs like domain/path/default-
It looks like default and a hash.
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Would surprise me if that was default, by typo3 itself. Probably some extension interfering with the slug generation, I would guess?

Comment: we used sluggi before, but we uninstalled it. I thought of news?

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 automatically creates this type of slug when a new page is inserted and saved without the creator giving it a title.
After adding a title, the slug can be renewed.

Comment: thats true, but the title is called "default title" not "default-hashnumber"